# Python Face-Recognition reach

Tags: python, face-recognition

I have a python code which detects faces, but if I am 3 meters away, it won't recognize me anymore... I am new to python and I think I can do more, if you can tell me the code I have to change.

Can somebody help me?

````
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
# img = captureScreen()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, facesCurFrame)

    for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
        faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
        
        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)

        
        name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
        
        if not matches[matchIndex]:

        else:
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)  
            cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            
            

    cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    ```
````

Comment: Does the library you used support image in grayscale or such? Maybe consider processing the input with grayscaling/canny edge/threshold, it may allow the program to recognize the contour of a face better, might improve in range

Comment: also if possible, please attach a demo video too, so that more people can see the results (we can also find out if its background color issue/brightness)

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/ , nvm, just found the documentation, you can change the sensitivity and tolerance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is rather in the big distance and small face then in algorithm.
face_recognition.face_locations() has an argument:
number_of_times_to_upsample
Try to set it 2 or more: as much as smaller faces to be found.

Comment: Also, f_r.face_encodings() also has two useful arguments: num_jitters and model.  Set the first in 2 or more and the second as "large". However, all that things multiply the time needed for image processing.

Comment: Nice, But don't set it to more than two.